# Move Cursor using Arrow Keys in Assembly

Tags: assembly

Hi I'm new to Assembly and I was making a program that would move my cursor anywhere on the screen using arrow keys, here is my code :

```
mov si, 0
mov dh, 0
mov dl, 0

menu:
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h

    cmp ah, 48h  ;Up Arrow key 
    je up

    cmp ah, 50h  ;Down Arrow key 
    je down

    cmp ah, 4Dh  ;Right Arrow key 
    je right

    cmp ah, 4Bh  ;Left Arrow key 
    je left

    jmp exit

up:
    mov ah, 3  ;Get current position
    int 10h

    mov ah, 2  ;Move cursor Up
    sub dh, 1
    int 10h

    jmp menu

down:
    mov ah, 3  ;Get current position
    int 10h

    mov ah, 2  ;Move cursor Down
    add dh, 1
    int 10h

    jmp menu

right:
    mov ah, 3  ;Get current position
    int 10h

    mov ah, 2  ;Move cursor Right
    add dl, 1
    int 10h

    jmp menu

left:
    mov ah, 2  ;Get current position
    int 10h

    mov ah, 3  ;Move cursor Left
    sub dl, 1
    int 10h

    jmp menu

exit: 


int 020
```

The Up, Down and Right arrow keys are working fine, but the Left arrow key doesn't seem to work. I was hoping you could tell me why. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a comment or two?

Comment: Also, for all the other cases, you read the position first (ah = 3), then set the position.  For `left` you set the position (ah = 2) then read the position.

Comment: . . . I can't believe I missed that. I feel really stupid right now. That was it. That was the problem. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Returning from the application won't work using `int 020` Do take care to write the correct number affix to specify hexadecimal. Use `int 20h` or `int 0x20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the comment to an Answer so this can get closed:

For all the other cases, you read the position first (ah = 3), then set the position (which makes sense). For `left` you set the position (ah = 2) then read the position.